# k-sample test for equality of means

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have seen that there exists tests which see if k samples share the same variance such as the Levene's test.

I was wondering if there is an equivalent test when means are wanting to be examined.

An non-parametric test would be needed here.

Comment: Most non-parametric tests are based on a stronger or slightly different null hypothesis, such none of the distributions is stochastically dominant.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Wallis_one-way_analysis_of_variance.

Comment: @whuber Does stochastic domaine imply difference in mean? I have seen people use the Mann Whitney U test for a difference in medians so does this not apply to the Kruskal-Wallis test?

Comment: Yes, stochastic dominance implies a difference in mean--but the implication does not go the other way.

Comment: @whuber If I dont reject the null, do I conclude the samples are from the same distribution? The reason I ask is I also performed the Levene test and rejected the null implying a difference in variance. So how can the KW test tell us the distributors are the same.

Comment: The null in the KW test does not assert all distributions are identical.

Comment: @whuber okay so the null is that $P(X \leq Y ) = P(Y \leq X)$?

Comment: @whuber If we reject the null and accept that one sample stochastically dominates another, then can we conclude the means differ even thought that was not the null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valid conclusions from a Kruskal-Wallis test can be difficult when populations have markedly different shapes.
Here we use three samples of size $n=100$ from
$\mathsf{Beta}(.1,.1)$ with mean $\mu_1 = 1/2,$
$\mathsf{Beta}(5,1)$ with mean $\mu_2 = 5/6,$ and
$\mathsf{Beta}(3,3)$ with mean $\mu_3 = 1/2.$

Densities of the three distributions are shown below:

[image]

Sampling in R:

```
set.seed(2021)
x1 = rbeta(100, .1, .1)
x2 = rbeta(100, 5, 1)
x3 = rbeta(100, 3, 3)
x = c(x1,x2,x3);  gp=rep(1:3, each=100)
```

The three sample means are as follows:

```
mean(x1); mean(x2); mean(x3)
[1] 0.5259448
[1] 0.8361308
[1] 0.498663

hdr="Boxplots of Samples from BETA(.1,.1) [red], BETA(5.1) [green], BETA(3,3)"
boxplot(x ~ gp, col=c("red", "green", "blue"), main=hdr)
```

[image]

A Kruskal-Wallis test (not ordinarily recommended for comparing distributions of different shapes) shows a highly significant difference among the three samples.

```
kruskal.test(x ~ gp)

        Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  x by gp
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 59.016, df = 2, p-value = 1.531e-13
```

Sometimes empirical CDF (ECDF) plots are used to judge visually whether one sample
stochastically dominates another. A dominating sample will tend to plot to the
right (hence below) samples it dominates. Here it seems clear that Sample 2 (green)
dominates Sample 3 (blue), but not so clear whether Sample 2 dominates Sample 1 (red).

```
hdr="ECDFs of Samples from BETA(.1,.1) [red], 
     BETA(5.1) [green], BETA(3,3)"
plot(ecdf(x1), col="red", main=hdr)
 lines(ecdf(x2), col="green2")
 lines(ecdf(x3), col="blue")
```

[image]

Sometimes two-sample Wilcoxon rank sum tests are used *ad hoc* to
determine differences is 'location' or 'domination'. Here are the P-values from two
such tests,
but I will leave the interpretation up to you. Ordinarily, one would want
to see a P-value below about 1% or 2% (according to the Bonferroni method
of avoiding 'false discovery') in order to declare differences.

```
wilcox.test(x2,x1)$p.value
[1] 0.06075133
wilcox.test(x2,x3)$p.value
[1] 2.750473e-24
```

Roughly estimated probabilities $P(X_2 > X_1)\approx 0.58$ and
$P(X_2 > X_3)\approx 0.92.$

```
quantile(replicate(10^6, mean(sample(x2) > x1)), c(.025,.975))
 2.5% 97.5% 
 0.54  0.61 
quantile(replicate(10^6, mean(sample(x2) > x3)), c(.025,.975))
 2.5% 97.5% 
 0.88  0.95
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To conclude, there are no tests that can compare means without the need of the same shape?

Comment: No simple answer. Need to specify exact situation. Sometimes 'same shape' means same var also. Welch t test will compare means of 2 _normal_ distributions with different variances. // Kolmogorov-Smirnov will compare samples to see if their populations have same shape. Might distinguish btw large enough samples from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=\sigma=1)$ and $\mathsf{Exp}(1).$ which has unit mean and SD:  `ks.test(rnorm(10,2,1),rexp(10))$p.val` may not reject, but `ks.test(rnorm(100,1,1),rexp(100))$p.val` often does. // Can find LR test to distinguish btw 2 exp'l distn's w/ $\ne$ means.